# How to draw a simple line dynamic graph on iPhone 

Tags: iphone, graph

How do I draw a simple line dynamic graph on the iPhone? The x-axis should show the profit by default and the y-axis should show the loss value.
I'm trying the plot, but I am unsuccessful. Do you have any ideas or examples? Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Please help in solving a problem. i have stuck in this from the last 4 days. i want to draw a simple dynamic line graph without using coreplot .How to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it. use a simple line graph calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Core-plot is a good framework to do the graphs. Or draw manually using quartz2d

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom view to handle your graphic. And in this view, do something like this (not tested, just written on the fly):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1.0, 0, 0.0, 1);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0);
    for(NSInteger *i  in profits)
    {
         CGContextAddLineToPoint( ctx, 10, [i intValue]);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```